# ResumableSource in http conduit results in "Cannot construct an infinite type" error

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

I am trying to create a function that creates a Source given some parameters to connect to a URL while being correctly in the ResourceT monad. I am trying the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Control.Monad.IO.Class       (liftIO)
import           Data.Conduit                 (($$), yield, unwrapResumable)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List            as CL
import           Network.HTTP.Conduit
import           Network.HTTP.Types           (methodPost)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT)

runquery manager  = do
  initreq <- parseUrl "http://localhost/test"
  let request = initreq{method=methodPost, requestBody=RequestBodyLBS "test"}
  response <- http request manager
  (httpsource, finalizer) <- unwrapResumable (responseBody response)
  httpsource
  finalizer

main = do
  manager <- newManager conduitManagerSettings
  runResourceT $ (runquery manager $$ CL.mapM_ (liftIO . print))
```

It does not work, I get 'cannot construct the infinite type' error from the compiler. I can `return (httpsource,finalizer)` (or just the whole responseBody) and use it later, but it seems to me strange. What is the proper way to write this code and why do I get the infinite type error?

Without type signature, I get the following error:

```
test.hs:17:3:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
      m
      ~
      conduit-1.2.4:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM
        () ByteString m
    Expected type: m ()
      Actual type: Source m ByteString
    Relevant bindings include
      finalizer :: m () (bound at test.hs:16:16)
      httpsource :: Source m ByteString (bound at test.hs:16:4)
      response :: Response
                    (conduit-1.2.4:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ResumableSource
                       m ByteString)
```

When I add a signature, which (I hope should be):

```
runquery :: Manager -> Source (ResourceT IO) ByteString
```

I get an error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘conduit-1.2.4:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM
                       () ByteString (ResourceT IO)’
              with ‘ResourceT IO’
Expected type: conduit-1.2.4:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM
                 () ByteString (ResourceT IO) ()
  Actual type: Source
                 (conduit-1.2.4:Data.Conduit.Internal.Conduit.ConduitM
                    () ByteString (ResourceT IO))
                 ByteString
```

I am probably doing something that couldn't be done, but I cannot quite see where is the problem.

Comment: can you please post the error? it's hard to tell without copy&pasting and actually compiling your code otherwise

Comment: btw: you should add type-signatures - even though Haskell will do it's best to infer them ;)

Comment: ok - the obvious problem is that you need to lift the `finalizer` before using it - but why do you even use `http` instead of `httpLbs` or even `simpleHttp`?

Comment: Lifting finalizer doesn't help, and the unwrapResumable type is ` MonadIO m => ResumableSource m o -> m (Source m o, m ())`, which means no lifting is necessary (I don't quite get this either). I don't use httpLbs/simpleHttp because there will be lots of data which I would like to process in a streaming manner.

Comment: then you should use [conduits operators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.4.1/docs/Data-Conduit.html#v:-36--36-) (there are quite afew) and if you choose the right ones they will handle the finalizers for you - btw: of course you don't need to lift the `Source m` part - you are in this monad here - but the finalizer is *only* in `m` and this is the source of the error here (also even if the `finalizer` would be of the right type you surely don't won't it to generate the result for you (it would only be `()`))

Comment: That's actually what I am trying to do. I am trying to make the `runquery manager` be a conduit, so that I can use the conduit operator (`$$` in the main function). The finalizer is not the problem, I have commented it out and it didn't help; the problem is with the `httpsource` where the `m` type gets somehow mixed up. The return value of finalizer `()` is OK, as the `runquery` is a `Source` and that is expected to return `()`.

Comment: I am slowly getting it, and it seems to me that the http-conduit is not a right way to do things; writing a custom conduit using http-client responseOpen/responseClose will be probably a few lines and will probably do just what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unwrapResumable, http, and the finalizer need to run in a resourceT appear to only work in a MonadResource context, (such as resourceT), so you have to lift them into it.

```
runquery :: MonadResource m => Manager -> Source m ByteString
-- or runquery :: Manager -> Source (ResourceT IO) ByteString
runquery manager  = do
  initreq <- parseUrl "https://localhost/test"
  let request = initreq{method=methodPost, requestBody=RequestBodyLBS "test"}
  response <- lift $ http request manager
  (httpsource, finalizer) <- lift $ unwrapResumable (responseBody response)
  httpsource
  lift finalizer

main :: IO ()
main = do
  manager <- newManager conduitManagerSettings
  runResourceT $ (runquery manager $$ CL.mapM_ (liftIO . print))
```